# Is subclassing a Luigi task possible?

Tags: python-3.x, class, subclass, luigi

I am using the [`luigi`](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html) workflow library. I would like to subclass its `luigi.Task` class to add a few more of my own methods and parameters.

The usual object pattern would be:

```
class MockClassA():
    pass

class MockClassB():
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo = foo

>>> MockClassB(12).foo
<<< 12
```

However, when I do:

```
class Transform(luigi.Task):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo = foo
```

I get:

```
>>> Transform(12)
<<< [...] UnknownParameterException: Transform[args=(12,), kwargs={}]: takes at most 0 parameters (1 given)
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: it probably defines `__new__` as well

Comment: I don't see it doing so in the [source](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/task.py#L149). (unless the `six.add_metaclass(Register)` decorator does so; not familiar with `six`, but I highly doubt it)

Comment: Here's the actual stacktrace: https://i.fluffy.cc/sVJCJ9Xfz8tCtWmJvkmV0jWNhPjcTrxf.html  It's crashing inside `Register.__call__` (`Register` is a metaclass, added with `six.add_metaclass`)

Comment: Yes, I was about to take it back after looking closer. Meta-programming hidden away in a compatibility library...

Is it then not possible to subclass a meta-classed class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual crash here is due to a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) running on instantiation.

From reading the [luigi docs](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html) it seems you are supposed to define parameters to your class as class attributes (`luigi.Parameter`) and let their metaclass machinery take care of the constructor.

I believe your example would be written something like this:

```
class Transform(luigi.Task):
    foo = luigi.Parameter()
```

Comment: This is fair. Thanks for spotting what I missed.